# How to decouple Constr from Data

Tags: plutus, builtindata

Imagine I have the following field in the Datum:

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "int": 3810998862
        },
        {
            "int": 18446744073709552000
        }
    ],
    "constructor": 3
}
```

I am retrieving this field in the Plutus script and converting to Data type. The final result I am left with is:

```
price :: PlutusTx.BuiltinData
```

This variable is of type:

```
Constr Integer [Data]
```

How can I retrieve/decouple only [Data] part and ditch this Constr with Plutus (without Plutarch)?

Saw something with `UnConstrData`, but I cannot make it work:

```
test = UnConstrData (PlutusTx.unsafeFromBuiltinData price)
```

Getting:

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `BuiltinData -> t'
                  with actual type `DefaultFun'
    * The function `UnConstrData' is applied to one argument,
      but its type `DefaultFun' has none
      In the expression: UnConstrData price
      In an equation for `x': x = UnConstrData price
```

Thanks